# Create video project with the same output rendering settings as input in pitivi?

Tags: pitivi

Usually I record videos of windows with applications, so they all have non-standard resolutions; for instance:

```
$ mediainfo ~/Videos/simplescreenrecorder-2023-02-16_05.10.40.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : ~/Videos/simplescreenrecorder-2023-02-16_05.10.40.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 357 KiB
Duration                                 : 11 s 700 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 250 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 11 s 700 ms
Bit rate                                 : 246 kb/s
Width                                    : 736 pixels
Height                                   : 460 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:10
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.024
Stream size                              : 352 KiB (99%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x3 / me=dia / subme=1 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=8 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=1:1.00
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

So, I would like to just open this file in Pitivi, and have the project settings for output rendering automatically inherit the above settings. But if I recall correctly from earlier times, there was no way to use the input file settings as project settings. Is it possible to do this with pitivi?

Answer (score 0):

Found this while writing this question: in Pitivi 2022.06, the Open butten can open only projects, not media (video) files. So, you can click New, and you get a new project - then you can drag & drop/Import your video file into the Media Library, and if it is the first file, Pitivi will say "The project settings have been set to match file *.mp4":

[image: pitivi media library]

If you add the clip to the timeline, you'll get by default a "Youtube" export preset, and you have to click on Advanced to see more about it:

[image: pitivi render window]

So, resolution width/height and FPS of the original video have been matched, codec x264 seems to be picked up as well, but cannot tell how accurately it is reproduced. Still, at least the most general video settings are copied to the project, which is what my question was originally about ...